# Find the indicial equation of $x^{3}y''+(\cos 2x-1)y'+2xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the indicial equation of $x^{3}y''+(\cos 2x-1)y'+2xy=0$
(where $y''$ stands for the second derivative)

The reference answer is $m(m-1)-2m+2=0$

I really don't know how to ... please help. thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does indical equation mean?

Comment: @Aatmaj : The equation for the leading power in the Frobenius power series expansion $y(x)=x^m\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^3y''+(\cos 2x-1)y'+2xy=0$$ near $x=0$, we use $\cos 2x-1\approx 1-2x^2-1=-2x^2$, then the ODE is
$$x^2y''-2xy'+2y=0$$
Let $y=x^m$, then
$$m(m-1)x^m-2mx^m+2x^m=0\implies m^2-3m+2=0 \implies m=1,2$$
So trhe indicial roots are $m=1,2$.

Comment: How to prove cos2x-1=-2x^2 at x=0

Comment: There is a series:$\cos z=1-z^2/2!+z^4/4!-z^6/6!+....$ for $|z|<<1$ yoy can write $\cos z \approx 1-z^2/2$..