# When referring to a question it is noted that expansion of cos 2x and cos x at |x| << 1 is taken as same and don't know why x = 2x is not taken?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is [Find the indicial equation of $x^{3}y''+(\cos 2x-1)y'+2xy=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3989755/find-the-indicial-equation-of-x3y-cos-2x-1y2xy-0)
I understood until the last part but couldn't figure out y' substitution part. Also, the part where y = x^m is taken to solve it simply whereas I am taking the entire general form of the Forbenius solution form. Thank you in advance.

Already been solved by Ahmed.

But Another arose,
It is alright to use this formula 'm(m-1) + pm + q = 0' wich is called as Indical equation, where p = limx->x0 [(x-x0)P(x)] and q = limx->x0 [(x-x0)^2Q(x)]

Comment: Not sure where you are getting that they said the series expansions are the same, they didn't say any such thing in their answer.

Comment: As $x \to 0$ we have both $$\cos(x) = 1 + O(x^2)\quad\text{and}\quad \cos(x) = 1 + O(x^2)$$Is that what you mean?

Comment: if anything I actually want the exact proof or any reference I could refer to.

Comment: Using the half-angle identity you get $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x=1-2x^2+O(x^4)$ using the more commonly known small-angle approximation $\sin x=x+O(x^3)$.

Comment: Z. Ahmed just gave the Taylor series for $\cos z$. As Triatticus has already said, they did not make any claim that $\cos 2x$ had the same Taylor series. Instead, they expected that any reader doing this level of mathematics would be capable of figuring out that to get the Taylor series of $\cos 2x$, you should make the substitution $z = 2x$ in the Taylor series for $\cos z$. (To facilitate that sustitution is the very reason they used $z$ as the variable instead of $x$.)

Comment: I already did that and am just about to edit my question. Anyway thanks